# How to deploy an app on heroku that uses playwright and doesnt crash?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, heroku, puppeteer, playwright

I am using playwright to scrape a websites contents. It all works fine in development. After deploying it on heroku, it sometimes works but 8/10 times it crashes. I noticed that It works right after I deploy it and then stops.

- I know that the servers on heroku (in the eco plan) sleep after 30 min, but I am scheduling the web scraping every 20 min and it does get executed (the issue is not that it doesnt get executed as the server sleeps but that it does get executed but crashes.

the errors I get:

`Uncaught Exception..: Error: read ENOTCONN , read ENOTCONN`

`Resource temporarily unavailable`

On heroku I added the
`https://github.com/mxschmitt/heroku-playwright-buildpack` 
before I added `heroku/nodejs`

I followed this `https://github.com/playwright-community/heroku-playwright-example`

Does anyone have an idea what I need to do different?